# How can I decide on what method to include and what to reject in an async.parallel array of Async methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

We're using the Async library's parallel() method to make parallel asynchronous API calls. So the code somewhat looks like this :

```js
async.parallel({
    a: (callback)=> aHelper(searchValue, callback),
    b: (callback) => bHelper(searchValue, callback),
    c: (callback) => cHelper(searchValue, null, callback)
},

function (error, result){
    console.log("Error", error)
    console.log("Results", result)
})
```

Now, we want to add a case here. We'll be adding a check for every value being passed into the parallel method. Let's say if I only want response of "a" and "c" (as per code), how do I avoid calling "b" in this case?
We tried a different approach for this.

```js
ParallelAsync.parallel({
    a: (callback)=> {true ? aHelper(searchValue, callback) : callback(true, null)},
    b: (callback)=> {false ? bHelper(searchValue, callback) : callback(true, null)},
    c: (callback) => {true ? cHelper(searchValue, callback): callback(true, null)}
},

function (error, result){
    console.log("Error", error)
    console.log("Results", result)
})
```

We tried this, but as per the documentation on **async's parallel** method, if any of our method is synchronous (in this case, it's callback(true, null) ) the flow will be executed synchronously. I also tried making callback(true,null) as a promise response, still the code is executed in a synchronous manner.

Is there any solutions to this issue?

Ref

1. async docs --> https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallel

Comment: What do you mean by "*the flow will be executed synchronously*"? What exactly is the problem? Does it not work?

Comment: Hey @Bergi So the code is executed synchronously here means, as according to the second code, where the value of "b" directly responds callback(true,null). So the other async parts are not executed with the result. 

So the response is : 
Error {b: true}
Results {b: null} 

It just skips the "a" and "c" value that were to be executed asynchronously.

Comment: Don't pass an error if you don't want it to short-circuit?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, can you please explain it in a little depth? I'mm passing the error in callback to as to avoid the response from to "b" .

Comment: If you still want the other results, don't error out. Use `callback(null, null)`

Comment: Hey @Bergi Sorry but still no luck.